# Easy mode for using Proguard in Android

Tags: android, proguard

When prepare to release the Android app, we would use Proguard to obfuscate the code which may break the app.

So once some error occurs, we modify that and build-release-test again and again, is there a simple way to do that?

Also, is it possible to see the obfuscated code directly in Android Stuido?

Comment: This is not what youre asking for but, what about the dump.txt, seeds.txt, mapping.txt, usage.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Retracing**

Retracing is what makes the obfuscated stack trace human-readable by replacing obfuscated names to the ones used in original source. In order to be able to retrace, make sure to save `mapping.txt` for every build you are about to test or send to someone. Mapping is unique for every build process.

Mapping can be found in

```
appModule/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
```

For retracing, there is a convenient tool named proguardgui, found in

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/proguard/bin/proguardgui.sh
```

(`*.sh` for UNIX systems, for other platforms expect different extension).

Choose "ReTrace", add a mapping.txt (make sure to use mapping.txt that was generated for that apk build) and paste the obfuscated stack trace into window. Press "ReTrace" on bottom right corner and you should get that stack trace with deobfuscated names.

Here's a screenshot with sample input I found on the Internet
[image]

**Decompiling**

> Also, is it possible to see the obfuscated code directly in Android Stuido?

No, but you might see the code by converting dex to jar and decompiling it.

```
dex2jar myapp.apk
jd-gui myapp-dex2jar.jar
```

dex2jar [github](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) page.

jd-gui from [github](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui) page.

**Practices I use to follow**

What works for me is whenever I add a library I add a proguard config for a library (usually provided by library developer).

There's also a project called [android-proguard-snippets](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets), thought they are mostly outdated, so make sure to check from library developer first.

For easy management, I use to split the proguard config for every library in a separate file. Below is a snippet from one of my build.gradle buildTypes for release

```
proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
proguardFile 'proguard-dart.pro'
proguardFile 'proguard-parceler.pro'
proguardFile 'proguard-retrolambda.pro'
proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
proguardFile 'proguard-rx-java.pro'
proguardFile 'proguard-support-design.pro'
proguardFile 'proguard-support-v7-appcompat.pro'
```

For objects used in `Firebase` serialization, add `@Keep` annotation.

For fields used by `Gson`, add `@SerializedName` annotations or use `@Keep` on an object.

Whenever I use reflection (or Animators, which are technically the same) I make sure to add proguard rule to keep the code accessed by reflection just after I write such code. In the end there will be probably nothing to fix.